# System of Linear differential equations with variable coefficients

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Could someone please suggest a technique for solving the following linear system of ODEs:

$$
\begin{array}{l}
i\alpha \frac{{dx(q)}}{{dq}} = \left( {\beta  - 2c\cos (q)} \right)x(q) - ig\,y(q)\\
i\alpha \frac{{dy(q)}}{{dq}} = \left( {\beta  + 2c\cos (q)} \right)y(q) - ig\,x(q)
\end{array}
$$

where $\alpha$, $\beta$, $c$ and $g$ are constants.

In order to solve this equation, I changed it to the following linear second order differential equation for $x(q)$,

$$
{\alpha ^2}\frac{{{d^2}x(q)}}{{d{q^2}}} + 2i\alpha \beta \frac{{dx(q)}}{{dq}} + \left( {{g^2} - {\beta ^2} + 4{c^2}{{\cos }^2}(q) + 2i\alpha c\sin (q)} \right)x(q) = 0
$$
But I can not solve this equation, too.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Let's change the variables to polar cordinate:
$$
x=r \cos (\theta)\\
y=r  \sin(\theta)\\
$$
Then we have :
$$
i\alpha \dot r \cos (\theta) - i\alpha r\sin (\theta)\dot \theta=(\beta-2c\cos(q))r \cos(\theta)-igr \sin(\theta)\\
i\alpha \dot r \sin (\theta) +i\alpha r\cos(\theta)\dot \theta=(\beta+2c\cos(q))r \sin(\theta)-igr \cos(\theta)\\
$$
Playing with the equations  we get:
$$
i\alpha \dot\ln r=\beta-2c\cos(q)\cos(2\theta)-ig\sin(2\theta)\\
i\alpha \dot \theta=2c\cos(q)\sin(2\theta)-ig\cos(2\theta)\\
$$
Now $\theta$ can be obtained independently and $\ln(r)$ will be just an integral of known functions.